# Problemas ao adicionar vários elementos no ArrayList

Tags: java

Estou praticando java e estou com problemas para imprimir os resultados dentro do ArrayList. Só mostra o último resultado digitado.

```
public class ArrayList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        List dados = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
        String resp;
        String nome;
        int idade;
        do {
            System.out.println("Nome: ");
            nome = teclado.next();
            System.out.println("Idade: ");
            idade = teclado.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Quer continuar ? ");
            resp = teclado.next();
            dados.add(nome);
            dados.add(idade);
        } while (!resp.equalsIgnoreCase("não"));

        for (int i = 0; i < dados.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Nome: " + nome + "\nIdade: " + idade);

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite carlos... vi muito pouco de java , mas pelo que me parece você esta printando
somente a variável nome e idade .. Não esta acessando diretamente o array.

Concorda comigo que toda vez que você entra dentro do DO , você atribuiu um novo valor, pra nome e idade?
por exemplo
primeira iteração:
Nome = "Pedro"
Idade = 27

Segunda iteração:
Nome = 'Carlos'
idade = 20

O valor final da variável nome e idade , sera carlos e 20 ...

Tente acessar seu array...

Answer (score 0):

Seu código precisa de pequenos ajustes, ficaria mais ou menos assim.
apenas defini o tipo da lista, foi modificado a mudança no for para fazer o loop, após tudo é sempre bom lembrar de fechar o recurso.

```java
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<String> dados = new ArrayList<String>(); // você precisa definir o tipo, isso pode ser uma instancia de obj
        String resp;
        String nome;
        String idade;
        do {
            System.out.println("Nome: ");
            nome = teclado.next();
            System.out.println("Idade: ");
            idade = teclado.next();
            System.out.println("Quer continuar ? ");
            resp = teclado.next();
            dados.add(nome);
            dados.add(idade);
        } while (!resp.equalsIgnoreCase("não"));

        for (int i = 0; i < dados.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Nome: " + dados.get(i) + "\nIdade: " + dados.get(i+1));
            i++;
        }
        teclado.close();
    }
```

outro exemplo se tratando de java moderno seria subistituir todo esse **for** por apenas:

```java
dados.forEach(System.out::println);
```

é bom lembrar que no lugar onde se colou os dados seria a sua classe específica com seus atributos, ficaria bem melhor. fica a dica.

Você quase acertou, está no caminho certo pois tentou.

Answer (score 0):

Se mudar a linha:
`List dados = new java.util.ArrayList<>();`

Para:
`ArrayList<string> dados = new java.util.ArrayList<>();`

Altere também o tipo de dados de *"idade"* de *int* para *String*.

Pra acessar um elemento numa ArrayList use o método *.get()*, dentro dos parênteses coloca o index de referência (depois do loop *for*, é só substituir teu system.out por: `System.out.println(dados.get(i));`